# GUI Composition in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, custom-controls

I have experience building GUIs in Java, C#, and C++ using the WinAPI. I'm attempting my first GUI in C++ using Qt and I have a bit of a transition problem. In any of the other three GUI paradigms, I could create my own GUI components, extend existing JPanels, etc. and end up with a custom-made GUI element that I could add to other GUI windows. C# is particularly good at this as anything I create automatically shows up in the Toolbox after it compiles.

From what I can see there are only two options in Qt and I'm hoping there is something I'm missing. The options are:

- Create a custom Widget which may then be imported using a widget container promoted to the right widget.
- Build what I like and drag it to scratchpad, from where I can replicate it to my heart's content.

The problem is that I want dynamically add/remove GUI elements at run time. For example, I have a Model-View-Control pattern. The view and control are two different panels in the GUI. When I switch to a different view in one panel, I want to remove the control from the other panel and replace it with the right control for the new view.

From what I can tell, I could do this using custom widgets, but it seems extremely heavy handed to do this for tons of minor widgets in composition to a greater capability. And although I can do the kind of composition I want in scratchpad, I can't figure out how to dynamically add something I have saved in scratchpad.

It is also possible that there is a Qt way of doing things which I have not found. For instance, I have some friends that have successfully created the effects above using different tabs. That seems like a cheap answer, which I could use, but I'd like to believe that Qt has sufficient flexibility to let me build any kind of GUI.

Any suggestions would be helpful

---------------------Improved example--------------------

Let me use the example code that @m7913d gave. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html) Suppose that I want to make this portion of the gui into a reusable component which i can add to any GUI I want. How do I do that?[image: GUI element]

If this was C# I would create a new user control, add the GUI elements, set up the code that makes the unit work as a whole and possibly set up event listeners or properties of the user control as a whole. then I can instantiate, add, and remove them at will from the rest of the GUI. That is what I want.

Comment: I have only a little experience with Qt but I know that each window is a form, which produces a class. So I can make instances of classes using regular pointers and memory allocation and such. To exchange info between windows, Qt has a SIGNAL/SLOT system where events trigger signals that can be read by slots. For example if I wanted to click and button in one window and change a value in another, I could create a signal from the button and a slot to the value and handle the call from there

Comment: I'm having trouble (myself knowing Qt, .NET WinForms and a bit of raw WinAPI) understanding what you want to achieve. With Qt, of course you can extend existing widgets by inheriting them, [I used this a lot](https://github.com/Zirias/shuttercontrol/blob/master/src/avrwidget.h). You can add child widgets to a layout and remove them, or just hide and show them.

Comment: Then, I never heard of a "Model-View-Control" pattern, only "Model-View-Controller" (and in *this* pattern, the *controller* definitely isn't a GUI element)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, they an MVC pattern implements the GUI as a "Model-View-Controller", but Qt doesn't use a "Model-View-Control" pattern. It uses an "MV" pattern, where the view and controllers are combined. They document this pretty extensively.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

Comment: Also, there are a lot of good ways to implement: subclassing is often a good way to go along with signals/slots. You could (if you have a small number of fixed widgets) simply toggle the visibility of widgets upon a signal, or you could dynamic `addWidget/removeWidget` from a parent (like `QStackedWidget`, or `QTabWidget`) to control the layout upon a signal.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I'm aware of MVVM, I was refering to the OP writing "Model-View-Control" (*without* "ler") and explaining "*The view and control are two different panels in the GUI*" -- if he means MVC, a *controller* is nothing visible in a UI.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, I just don't think the OP knows what MVC is.

Comment: Qt allows you to change the layout completely dynamically. In fact, everything you do in the Qt Designer is translated to plain C++ code. It may be helpful to have a look at it at the C++ code generated by Qt Designer.

Comment: This [basic layout example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html) may be useful too. Or an overview of [Layout Management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) in Qt.

Comment: @Felix-Palmen, this is a great help. Not quite what I was looking for, but I can see what you mean about subclassing existing widgets. I will add this tool to by Qt design toolbox. Thanks,

Comment: Some of you are getting wrapped up around MVC. The point here is that if you have gui elements, full panels with multiple widgets all collaborating signal-slot behind the scene, how do you save and reuse that panel as a widget.

Comment: @BSD regarding to the last line of your question, to make a _bunch of widgets_ reusable, you just create a subclass of `QWidget` containing the _layouts/widgets_ you want (you can do that either with code or a .ui file). And then, you create instances of that composed-widget like any other native widget. Of course you can add your own signals or slot, and add whatever your want to the interface of that custom widget, implement some behaviours in slots/methods etc